# Как перевести число написанное в байтах на время (чч:мм:сс)?

Tags: c

Привет всем.

Как можно перевести число, например, 1244824 в обычное время, формат `чч:мм:сс`.
Может как-то взять 4 старших бита, и с ними что-то сделать?

Comment: Вероятно, по той же формуле, по которой переводят метры в килограммы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Странный вопрос. "Просто число" никак не связано со временем. 1244824 это количесво рожденных енотов от Рождества Христова? Или количесво оборотов Марса вокруг Солнца?

Если это количесво секунд от 1 января 1970 UTC (Полученые от time()). То можно можно воспользоваться [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) Пример, приведенный по ссылке, можно преобразовать что бы получать данные в формате чч:мм:сс.

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char buffer [80];

time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

strftime (buffer,80,"%H:%M:%S.",timeinfo);
```

Comment: 1244824 было время написанное в байтах.

Comment: Я опять повторюсь что просто число не связано со временем. Записано ли оно в байтах, мегабайтах, на бумаге или высечено на камне. Если вы скажете откуда вы взяли это число, то возможно вам смогут помочь.

Comment: x = u∙t
∴ t = x/u
где x - количество байт,
t - время в секундах
u - скорость Интернета из справочника IETF [байт/сек]

Comment: было получено с сервера по определенному айпи адресу. Да я уже сделал... Оказывается это было слово HTTP =)))